# The version of ODBC Source, clsid {9EAC76F9-8D61-4F12-9E7B-529CF31765A1} is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow. "

Tags: ssis

I have SSIS package which was working fine, but i changed the query and redeploy it now its giving the error.

The version of ODBC Source, clsid {9EAC76F9-8D61-4F12-9E7B-529CF31765A1} is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.

I have checked the version both are same.

Regards,
Muzaffar

Answer (score 0):

WOW it's so simple, i was deploying the only package which i have changed, deploying the complete project work for me. Below is the link of forum where i got the answer. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fa7cd061-3cf1-4ba0-8594-9125f5b0271b/version-incompatibility-for-script-task-called-from-a-dataflow?forum=sqlintegrationservices